# flutter firestore: if conditions not responding accurately

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I'm trying to use if condition to fetch data from firestore. However, the conditions are not really working well. In my code I wrote if `snapshot.hasData` it should return a `Text`, else it should return a `TextField`. However, it returns a Text even whether or not there is a data in the database.
And when I make it `!snapshot.hasData`, it returns a TextField whether or not there is data.
Can someone help me with this?

My code

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
CollectionReference ads = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ADS');

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: ads.doc(uid).snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 return Center(
                        child: Text("Sorry! You already have a data")
                              )}else {
                 return SingleChildScrollView(
                           child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                TextField() // and the rest of the code
]
)

)
}
       
}
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
CollectionReference ads = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ADS');

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: ads.doc(uid).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists) {
    
          return Center(
            child: Text("Sorry! You already have data"),
          );
        } else {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(), 
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```